# Python Django templates for dummy

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

First of all, I am sorry, for this is surely a duplicate. However, I couldn't find a question on stackoverflow that is not about advanced Django's templates features.

I followed [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/) religiously. My project structure is as follows:

```
poll_site
  ./db.sqlite3
  ./manage.py
  ./polls
    ./admin.py
    ./__init__.py
    migrations
    models.py
    __pycache__
    tests.py
    views.py
  ./poll_site
    ./__init__.py
    ./settings.py
    ./urls.py
    ./wsgi.py
  ./templates
    ./admin
      base_site.html
```

Last line of `settings.py` is

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), )
```

(I have tried `TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]`)

`templates/admin/base_site.html` is as follows:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Polls site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{site_header|default:_('Monkey') }}</a>
</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

However, when I go to my website, I see
[image: Django administrator image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#default) filter outputs it's parameter only then the value is empty.  In your case `site_title` and `site_header` are not empty so `default` don't do anything.

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Polls site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Monkey' %}</a>
</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

BTW you don't need to override admin template to change title/header.  Read [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes) of the documentation.

Comment: I had to leave `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}` as first line if I wanted something besides titles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template never got rendered in the first place.

Translation in templates is done with trans and blocktrans tags and not via the _ (which usually refer to ugettext or other siblings)

My suggestion is: You can `print TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings.py to see the actual path & make sure that it's right.